# Linux missing disk space

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

I have KVM vps with strange disk usage:

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb              493G  1.2G  466G   1% /
tmpfs                 4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1              96M   41M   51M  45% /boot
```

```
# du -sh /
du: cannot access `/proc/1633/task/1633/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/1633/task/1633/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/1633/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/1633/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
1021M   /
```

How could it be? Where are ~20G of free space?

Comment: Could you please modify your output for the same units of measure?

Comment: Run `du` with -x switch, this way it won't go into other file systems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you talk about the discrepancy between 493GB total space, 1.2G used and 466GB free. This is likely the result of the usual 5% of disk space that is reserved for `root` and not generally available.

To check for this, please add the output of at least the `Reserved block count` from

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdb
```

to your question (provided you use ext3 or ext4 as a filesystem)

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, `Reserved block count: 6553600`.